# Adding conditionals to a batch script loop to filter out unwanted results in the windows command line

Tags: batch-file

Currently, I have a list of file ID's as the values of a variable named `located_file_ids`. I want to check if the files within a large directory, `PHOTO_MASTERS_DIR`, have any of those id's as substrings within their basenames.

ex. `file id = c00023` 
sr_**c00023**_m145.tif = match

If there is a match I want to copy them to a directory, `COPIED_IMAGES_DIR`, otherwise add it to the `remaining_ids` variable value.

I am having issues with the script copying files that it shouldn't, so I decided to add some conditions.

ex. `file id = c00023`

- Filter out results that are .md5 files
  com_c00023_m145.**md5** = not a match
- Filter out results that have any letters directly in front of the file id
  sc-**b**c00023_m145.tif = not a match
- Filter out results that have any numbers directly behind the file id
  smith-folder__c00023**015**-m145.tif = not a match

edit with more clarification-
Current needs: (or atleast what I think the current needs are...)

1. Loop over the list and search for an absolute match of the current id
2. Test for and skip if it is a .md5 file
3. Test for and skip if the current id that was located in the file name directly has a letter preceding it.
4. Test for and skip if the current id that was located in the file name directly has a number following it.

- (3 and 4 are currently the biggest problem areas at the moment...)
  The file names are not consistently named so there are no consistent delimiters, but the file id will never have a letter directly in front of it or a number directly behind it (If either of these are ever the case - it is a different id and should be filtered out)

Adding conditions made it worse, and most files that should match are getting skipped now.

Here is the relevent code snippet.

```bash
set "remaining_ids="

:: Loop for Photo Masters directory
for %%i in (%located_file_ids%) do (
    set "found=false"
    for /R "%PHOTO_MASTERS_DIR%" %%f in (*%%i*) do (
        echo %%~nxf | findstr /R /C:"\<%%i\>" >nul && (
            echo %%~nxf | findstr /R /C:"[a-zA-Z]%%i" >nul && (
                rem Skip files with a letter directly in front of the file id
            ) || (
                echo %%~nxf | findstr /R /C:"%%i[0-9]" >nul && (
                    rem Skip files with a number directly behind the file id
                ) || (
                    echo %%~nxf | findstr /I /C:"md5" >nul && (
                        rem Skip files containing "md5" anywhere in the filename
                    ) || (
                        set "found=true"
                        echo %%f located
                        copy "%%f" "%COPIED_IMAGES_DIR%"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    if !found!==false (
        echo %%i not located
        set "remaining_ids=!remaining_ids! %%i"
    )
)
```

If you can see what the issue is, or have tips for how to redo this completely, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You have a batch file and should update the batch file to Powershell.

Comment: Santiago Squarzon : Why do you keep on removing Powershell when the OP original posing has Powershell.  I have a Powershell solution and if you remove Powershell than people will tell me the OP doesn't want PS.

Comment: @jdweng OP's question never had PowerShell code nor implied they were looking for a PowerShell solution. It only had the tag which was rightfully removed by another user after you decided to post a PS solution and re-add it again. I will keep removing it.

Comment: The question, should be tagged with the scripting language used for the submitted code. That is [[tag:batch-file]]. As there was absolutely no mention, or use, of PowerShell in the title, body text, or code, that was, IMO, rightfully removed. This site is not here to cater to code requests for one, and especially in any one of a list, of languages. In my opinion @jdweng, your free PowerShell coded answer does not fulfill the criteria of the question, and using a spammed tag as the basis of one is likely to attract these type of arguments.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon : The original posting had Powershell as tag and OP said "If you can see what the issue is, or have tips for how to redo this completely that would be very helpful."  I redid completely.

Comment: Even if your code was fully commented with supporting body text @jdweng, calling it a "tip" would be stretching the definition somewhat!

Comment: @Compo : You are a Conservative that is reading the words in OP question instead of the intent of what the OP wanted.  I'm more liberal and consider a "Better solution" a "Tip".

Comment: This site does not offer a free code writing service. Asking for one is grounds to qet your question closed. Providing one is only encouraging more poor quality questions from otherwise non contributing members, moving forward. BTW, that term has polititcal connotations which are offensive to me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following powershell which is tested.

```
$file_Ids = @('c00023','c00024','c0025','c00026')
$directory = 'C:\Temp\PHOTO_MASTER_DIR'
foreach($id in $file_Ids)
{
   $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory | Where-object {($_.name -match "[^A-Za-z]$id[^\d]") -and ($_.extension -ne '.md5')}
   foreach($file in $files)
   {
       Write-Host $file $file.fullname
   }
}
```

Comment: The question content, mentions 'not preceding the ID substring with a letter,' and 'not succeeding it with a number'. That does not imply that the file ID substring 'must be both preceded with, and succeeded by, an underscore', despite the examples showing that.

Comment: @Compo : Lets see what the OP says.  I can modify easily if the OP needs changes.

Comment: That's not how this is supposed to work. If you have questions regarding an understanding of the task, that is for the comment section. You shouldn't just post code, with absolutely no explanation of what it is written to do, especially when it does not do what their code attempted, or lists as its filters, _(notwithstanding that it isn't even in the tagged scripting language, so the OP likely cannot read it)_.

Comment: @Compo : I ran code with all the filters OP posted.  If some of the filters were not precise than the OP should add additional info to the posting so he gets the expected results.  At least I posted a working and tested solution.  And you shouldn't be changing what the OP wrote unless there are technical issues.  You are changing what you should not be changing.

Comment: No you used `_\`$id\`_` and excluded the `.md5` extension. The filters were no alphabet character directly preceding the ID, and no digit directly succeeding it. _It would have been easier for the OP to specify "ID's isolated between underscores", than create a set of filters, if that's all they wanted!_. Also, you have made an assumption that the file basenames all must begin with the substring, `sr_`, as that's not eplicit either in their text body or submitted code. Underscores weren't explicit either, but a much fairer assumption. Matches: `sr_1c00023_*`, `sr_c00023b_*`, `*_*1c00023b*_*`.

Comment: BTW, as you have decided to mention something I have changed, which I should not have, I would appreciate it if you could highlight that/those specifically for me, and I will rectify or put my counter arguments here accordingly. The idea is to make a question understandable to an international audience, and to keep it as succinct as possible, without overtrimming, or changing the parameters of the programming issue. It is not only for technical issues!

Comment: @Compo : We really shouldn't be arguing.  The OP posting needs some clarification.   I have a good start and was expecting that some tweaks would be needed.  The OP may know Regex and can make the changes himself.  I would use "^sr\`_\d*$id[A-Za-z]*\`_"

Comment: I'm not arguing! The OP has already provided some additional information, (3 hours ago). The filtering situation is still unclear, but my initial analysis was much closer than the assumptions you'd made. The OP mentioned the 'letter' and 'number' being not **directly** 'before' and 'following' the ID too. That still leaves the following as a match ```*_*b1c00023b1*_*```. The letter is indirectly before the ID, _(not directly)_, and the number is indirectly following the ID, _(not directly)_. And remember that the underscore has not been explicitly defined as part of the name either!

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance and I apologize if my ignorance of the posting rules caused any conflict. I messed around and pieced together a regex that seems to work well when I test with an id
(?!.*\.md5)(?<![a-zA-Z])(?!\d)currentID(?!\d)
Here is a link if anyone wants to see it in action - https://regex101.com/r/huqeF3/1

Comment: I updated the code with new Regex.  I think mine is simpler than yours.

Comment: I much prefer the updated regex in the answer above,along with the seperate extension exclusion, _(although there may be a minor efficiency hit)_, based upon what the filters seemed to specify. Although technically neither is a fix for the question code, so cannot be considered as a solution.

Comment: @Compo : The OP original posting has Powershell as a Tag and said "If you can see what the issue is, or have tips for how to redo this completely".  I consider my solution a "redo this completely".  People keep on editing the OP posting and remove the tag Powershell.

Comment: Completely 'rewriting' code, in a language not used in the question and submitting it with no commentary or supporting information has no worth to future readers looking for help for their code in another language.

Comment: @Compo : Look at Tags in original posting.  It said Powershell.  Why did people edit out a OPs wishes?

Comment: Have you read my previous conments and understood how this site works? There was no PowerShell code submitted, and no mention of PowerShell in the title or body text. The tag had no place there and was correctly removed. It does not matter whether the OP was happy for any other way of achieving the task, had they included e.g. vbscript, c++, python tags with no accompanying code using them, those would also have been removed too. We help programmers to fix their code, we do not write completely new code for them in another language just because we can. Your answer doesn't help batch scripters.

Comment: @Compo : I've got comments from others at Stackoverflow that alternate solutions are allowable.

Comment: What you appear to be telling me is that people have differing opinions. After well over half a century on this planet, that is not something which has caught me off guard. I have no idea why you are hounding me over a differing opinion; it was not myself who removed the tag, or stated that they'd continue to do so, but just another person who had a dissimilar opinion to you. Do you know what will happen if one particular language spammed solutions under every SO question not having submitted code in that language? This is not, and never has been, a site for pitting language against language.

Comment: @jdweng Updating to Powershell was a much better solution than my original code. Thanks for the recommendation. It seems to be sorted out now.

Comment: @Compo : My complaint is somebody remove the PS tag and then it looked like my solution was not what the OP wanted.  If the TAG was still there you probably wouldn't of started this conversation.

Comment: So take that up with them, their account name is easily viewed and they've already told you they did it. You also could redirect your anger to whomever downvoted you and/or voted to delete your answer; not myself, who gave you valid advice on the filtering criteria, and stated a preference for your regex. If you continue to harass me, I will downvote you myself, vote to delete you answer too, and report you to the Moderators.

Comment: @Compo : Does it make sense my answer has the check mark with -1 points?  I'm sorry that about the disagreement, but I've have had lots of issue with people recently who do not like me answering with different approaches.  Some moderators say alternate solutions are acceptable and other do not.

Comment: Yes; if the OP wanted an off topic code request to be furnished, and you obliged, it does not mean that your code answers the programming code issue posted, and their check mark does not change that. As for the downvote, I don't know when you received it, _(perhaps when your code didn't match requested filters)_, but I'd have no issue with anyone downvoting code without supporting text, or comments, and which is written in a completely different language to the submission. There is no correlation between 'usefulness to other users', i.e. voting, and 'OP acceptance', i.e. check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Without a clarified explanation of the required conditions, examples of filenames that should have been copied but were excluded, should not have been copied but were copied and any other undesired actions, ou're really asking how long is a piece of string, however -

Something you could try is for your `for...%%f` loop

```
for /R "%PHOTO_MASTERS_DIR%" %%f in (*_%%i_*) do if "%%~xf" NEQ ".md5" (
 ECHO copy "%%f" "%COPIED_IMAGES_DIR%"
)
```

Noting that this will obviously merely **show** the filenames for verification purposes.

**IF** the commands reported are correct, remove the `echo` keyword to actually do the copy.

**[NOT TESTED]**